# Can we change the date format in new Date() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently date is displaying as in this format **Sun Jan 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**, Can we display it just like **Jan 2012**? I want to display this date into **Month Year(Jan 2012)** format.

```js
   
   
     $(document).ready(function(){
     var ddate = new Date('January 01, 2012 00:0:00');
     
     document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = ddate;
      
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Can anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: You might want to check this question and the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1056728/3000771

Comment: This is a great answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10685571/295783

Comment: @mplungjan sorry to say you, but i am not capable to find the answer. Can you please help ?

Comment: you can do like this.
var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'short'};
var ddate = new Date('January 01, 2012 00:0:00');
ddate.toLocaleDateString("US", options);

Comment: Thanks @sureshkumar

Comment: @jasbir: There are 48 answers in the duplicate - one of them should be useful to you. If not then `var parts = ddate.split(" "); console.log(parts[1]+" "+parts[3]);`